# How can I let the database generate a date in code first entity framework 6?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a property `creationdate` in my *User* class and with the data annotation

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

I am telling EF that the database generates this property himself on insert.

The problem is that when I create a migration I have to manual edit the migration file to tell the created database that this column needs to be generated by the database like the following:

```
 CreateTable(
                "dbo.Comments",
                c => new
                    {
                        CommentId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        PostDate = c.DateTime(defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"),
                        Title = c.String(),
                        Content = c.String(),
                        IsApproved = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        User_UserId = c.Int(),
                        Event_EventId = c.Int(),
                        Subject_SubjectId = c.Int(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.CommentId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.User_UserId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Events", t => t.Event_EventId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Subjects", t => t.Subject_SubjectId)
                .Index(t => t.User_UserId)
                .Index(t => t.Event_EventId)
                .Index(t => t.Subject_SubjectId);
```

where I have to add

```
defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"
```

manually.. I expected that EF6 was smart enough to generate this himself by checking the property type.

Question: is there any relatively easy way to solve this issue, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe this:  [http://lancelarsen.com/entity-framework-code-first-computed-getdate/](http://lancelarsen.com/entity-framework-code-first-computed-getdate/)

Comment: I am doing it like that at this moment. But was hoping there is a automated way of generating that piece of code.

Comment: EF can't simply assume that you want any database-generated date property to be set by `GETDATE()`. It might as well be some complicated trigger.

Comment: @Fergers - EF doesn't have any detailed knowledge of the database itself.  That's what the mappings do, define how that should be mapped.  EF currently does not support extended metadata, like default value of the SQL because this isn't something that can be truly modeled by the ORM.

Comment: @erik thats a clear answer. Well I guess thia thread can be closed then! If you could answer this below then I can accept your answer.